# c++: Proper way of initializing struct

Tags: c++, c++03

Let's say I want to initialize both x and y to 0. What is the best way to initialize B in the C's initialization list? I'm more interested in C++03 way of doing this.

```
typedef struct A
{
    int x, y;
} A;

typedef struct B
{
    A a;
} B;

class C
{
public:
    C();
private:
    B b;
};
--------
C::C(): b(??) {}
```

Comment: create a constructor for each struct? note you don't need `typedef`

Comment: Structs are classes in C++. You don't need that C style `typedef`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
C::C() : b() {}
```

---

Note that you don't need the `typedef struct` trickery in C++. `struct Name {blah};` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Your `typedef struct` is too much `C-style`, you do not need it in C++.

Anyway, a `struct` can include a *non-default* constructor.

[Here](https://godbolt.org/g/ZyKJSb) a live example.

Structs with no-default constructors:

```
struct A {
  A(int _x = 0, int _y = 0) : x(_x), y(_y) { }
  int x, y;
};

struct B {
  A a;
  B(int x = 0, int y = 0) : a(x, y) { }
};
```

With default argument `B::B()` will construct an a object with `[x = 0; y = 0]`.

Answer (score 0):

In C++03 you can define in A and B constructor with two ints. In C you call B constructor wich just forwards arguments to A's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In your example both A and B structs behave like PODs - objects with default constructors and copy-assignments and obviously trivial destructors. 
In such case C++ allows to initialize these objects by passing parameters directly to members (no user-defined constructor is used).
For example :

```
A a1; // x and y initialized with default values (0 for int)
A a2{2}; // x initialized with 2, y with default
A a3{2, 4}; // x initialized with 2, y with 4
```

This also works for C++  style structs (without typedef and so on).
Look here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pod

**Update:**
in such case *{ }* have to be used instead of *( )*

Comment: `A a2(2);` and `A a3(2, 4);` are invalid. You probably mean `A a = {2}`

Comment: Yes, you are right. Such case requires *{ }* to initialize an object. Yet simple 
A a1;
should be enough to call default initializers (if A is truly a POD)